# Swing GUI lagging when I lead large text

Tags: java, swing

I am facing a problem with a Java Swing GUI. I have a variable string which contains a large text. I want to set that text to text Pane on GUI
but whenever I try the app blocks I can't use it till the text done from loading on the text Pane

I was trying to use the threads but it didn't work.
here's the code source:

```
Thread myThread = new Thread(){
     public void run(){

        ///// here sending the large text to Text Panle
        MoreInfo.setText(getinfo.getRelatedText()[TheQuestion.getSelectedIndex()]);
     }

 }

myThread.start();
```

Comment: Check [Lesson: Concurrency in Swing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/index.html) for a complete understand of your problem. Short version, you are doing the processing on the GUI thread, so the GUI have to wait the end of your methods before being able to process the following events

Comment: even with creating new thread still it's using the GUI thread?

Comment: Normaly, I would say that it should be fine, but since you have a problem here.... I would first use a more correct implementation like a `SwingWorker`, two check the methods your are using... provide a [mcve] for more help.

Answer (score 0):

Class `javax.swing.SwingWorker` is included in JDK since java 1.6

This class allows to run a task in the background.

There is a [tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/worker.html) on Oracle's Web site.

Comment: even after using it still the same problem

Comment: You should include a really short example to your answer.